# how to move mouse on top of screencapture: automation with Selenium & C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I need some general ideas on how to grab the mouse and make it move on top of a screencapture utility. I don't need details, just general ideas.I'm using Selenium Webdriver with C#.

I know about iterating through all of the open windows, selecting by class or title etc, and have no problem clicking on whatever I need to inside these windows (and on occasion using helpful tools such as  winspy++). However, the system I'm attempting to automate triggers a screenshotting  software, whereby the movement of the mouse triggers outlines to appear wherever the mouse is moved (and obviously, Dev tools in Chrome or IE are useless as the tools themselves are captured...). Forcing the mouse to move to any point using windows own e.g. SetCursorPos, does not trigger the screen capture which is already listening, as it were. Emulating a mouse movement across the screen with several position changes, doesn't trigger the screenshotting utility, which is usually primed with the mouse movement.

Any suggestions or pointers to useful info would be greatly appreciated, been stuck on this for a while despite reading around... What is the likely framework in place for screenshotting to function?

(I have tried using Actions class as well with MoveToElement etc, incidentally)

Comment: Show us the ways you tried to move a mouse. Also show the code of screencapture utility if you can or if not then provide us with screenshots at least.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to move mouse to an element (to hover an element) use the next code:

```
public void MoveMouseToElement(IWebElement target)
{
     Actions action = new Actions(Driver);
     action.MoveToElement(target).Perform();
}
```

So first locate the element and then move mouse to it.

Probably you can do the same with Javascript.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned I've tried that and it doesn't work - will edit my q